# To add items from a list in an alternating fashion to two new lists why doesn't this code work? (its says that player_1 is not defined)

Tags: python

```
def distribute(mylist):
    player_1=[]
    player_2=[]
    
    a=10
    
    for i in range(0,a):
        if i%2==0:
            player_1.append(mylist.append(i))
        else:
            player_2.append(mylist.append(i))
```

**Result**

```
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
distribute(mylist)
player_1
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-124-1c0f0ed63597> in <module>
----> 1 player_1
 
NameError: name 'player_1' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: You tried to evaluate `player_1` in your main program.  There is no such variable in the main.

Comment: `player_1` is local to `distribute()` and cant be accessed outside of it. That is why when it tried to look it up, it cant find it. Also unrelated but probably an error: `mylist.append(i)` returns `None` which is probably not what you wanted to append to `player_1`. If you want to have access to it afterwards, `return player_1` at the end.

```
def distribute(mylist):
    player_1=[]
    player_2=[]
    
    a=10
    
    for i in range(0,a):
        if i%2==0:
            player_1.append(mylist[i])
        else:
            player_2.append(mylist[i])
    return player_1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable as global.
And append doesn't return anything, so you will get None. Just append `i` into the list.

Like this:

```
def distribute(mylist):
    global player_1, player_2 #Anything you need to set
    player_1=[]
    player_2=[]
    a=10
    for i in range(0,a):
        if i%2==0:
            player_1.append(mylist[i])
        else:
            player_2.append(mylist[i])
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
distribute(mylist)
print(player_1)
```

Or you can return the result.

```
def distribute(mylist):
    player_1=[]
    player_2=[]
    a=10
    for i in range(0,a):
        if i%2==0:
            player_1.append(mylist[i])
        else:
            player_2.append(mylist[i])
    return player_1
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(distribute(mylist))
```

Returning is recommended.

Comment: your code doesnt actually use `mylist` which is being passed in. I suggested an edit :) +1

Comment: Ah, thank you :) Approved!